# pandas: how can I select rows in a timeseries that are "largest seen so far"?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns: a timeseries and a value. I would like a function that only selects rows in the dataframe that are the "highest seen value so far", e.g., traverse the rows from oldest to youngest and only when a value is greater than any seen so far, output the row associated with that value. For the dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([
        ['1/10/12',10],
        ['1/11/12',11],
        ['1/12/12',13],
        ['1/14/12',12],
        ['1/9/12',3],
        ['1/8/12',4],
        ['1/18/12',12],
        ],
        columns=['date','n'])
```

what I'd want is

```
      date   n
0   1/8/12   4
1  1/10/12  10
1  1/11/12  11
2  1/12/12  13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a new column:

```
df["cm"] = df["n"].cummax()

newdf = df[df.n == df.cm].drop("cm")
```

Comment: `cummax`! I did not know that function. Perfect. Thank you @Igor Rivin.